# How can I speed up my Java text file parser?

Tags: java, performance, file, parsing

I am reading about 600 text files, and then parsing each file individually and add all the terms to a map so i can know the frequency of each word within the 600 files. (about 400MB).

My parser functions includes the following steps (ordered):

- find text between two tags, which is the relevant text to read in each file.
- lowecase all the text
- string.split with multiple delimiters.
- creating an arrayList with words like this: "aaa-aa", then adding to the string splitted above, and discounting "aaa" and "aa" to the String []. (i did this because i wanted "-" to be a delimiter, but i also wanted "aaa-aa" to be one word only, and not "aaa" and "aa".
- get the String [] and map to a Map = new HashMap ... (word, frequency)
- print everything.

It is taking me about 8min and 48 seconds, in a dual-core 2.2GHz, 2GB Ram. I would like advice on how to speed this process up. Should I expect it to be this slow? And if possible, how can I know (in netbeans), which functions are taking more time to execute?

> unique words found: 398752.

CODE:

```
File file = new File(dir);
String[] files = file.list();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(dir + files[i])), encoding));
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            parsedString = parseString(line); // parse the string
            m = stringToMap(parsedString, m);
        }
    } finally {
        br.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Check this:

![enter image description here][1]

I don't know what to conclude.

---

EDIT: 80% TIME USED WITH THIS FUNCTION

```
    public String [] parseString(String sentence){
         // separators; ,:;'"\/<>()[]*~^ºª+&%$ etc..
        String[] parts = sentence.toLowerCase().split("[,\\s\\-:\\?\\!\\«\\»\\'\\´\\`\\\"\\.\\\\\\/()<>*º;+&ª%\\[\\]~^]");

        Map<String, String> o = new HashMap<String, String>(); // save the hyphened words, aaa-bbb like Map<aaa,bbb>

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<![A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÀÃÂÊÎÔÛáéíóúàãâêîôû-])[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÀÃÂÊÎÔÛáéíóúàãâêîôû]+-[A-Za-zÁÉÍÓÚÀÃÂÊÎÔÛáéíóúàãâêîôû]+(?![A-Za-z-])");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);

    // Find all matches like this: ("aaa-bb or bbb-cc") and put it to map to later add this words to the original map and discount the single words "aaa-aa" like "aaa" and "aa"
        for(int i=0; matcher.find(); i++){
           String [] tempo = matcher.group().split("-");
           o.put(tempo[0], tempo[1]);
        }
        //System.out.println("words: " + o);


        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(parts));

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : o.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            temp.add(key+"-"+value);
            if(temp.indexOf(key)!=-1){
                temp.remove(temp.indexOf(key));
            }
            if(temp.indexOf(value)!=-1){
                temp.remove(temp.indexOf(value));
            }
        }


        String []strArray = new String[temp.size()];
        temp.toArray(strArray);
                return strArray;

  }
```

600 files, each file about 0.5MB

EDIT3#- The pattern is no longer compiling each time a line is read. The new images are:

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suzBx.png): [image]

Comment: If Netbeans doesn't have a profiler, jvisualvm (ships with the JDK) has a simple one that can help. If that's not enough, you can try others like JProfiler.

Comment: I'm confused - the screenshot shows char[]s being the pig, not Integer[].  Can you clarify?

Comment: im waiting for the time analysis, i already know which functions is taking me the most time. Gonna post it here, hope you can help soon :p

Comment: See my updated answer for a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to increase your heap size, if you haven't already, using -Xmx.  For this app, the impact may be striking.

The parts of your code that are likely to have the largest performance impact are the ones that are executed the most - which are the parts you haven't shown.

**Update** after memory screenshot

Look at all those Pattern$6 objects in the screenshot.  I think you're recompiling the pattern a lot - maybe for every line.  That would take a lot of time.

**Update 2** - after code added to question.

Yup - two patterns compiled on every line - the explicit one, and also the "-" in the split (much cheaper, of course).  I wish they hadn't added split() to String without it taking a compiled pattern as an argument.  I see some other things that could be improved, but nothing else like the big compile.  Just compile the pattern once, outside this function, maybe as a static class member.

Comment: yes. I checked it an uploaded the code. Please check. I not so used to patterns and i must be doing something programatically-wrong, im sorry if it is the case, but as i said, im not very used to patterns.

Comment: i took pattern out of that place, and putted it in the main class, and passed it throught parameters in parseString class. It doesnt seems to have much effect, still taking the same time.

Comment: @user974594 - Sorry for blind alley - it's certainly been a performance problem for me in the past.  I should know better than to guess on performance problems.  Depending on your profiling tools, either look at the library calls to see what's taking a long time, or, if that doesn't work, break the function up so you can see which part(s) are pigs.

Comment: This was the best answer for me. The problem was that Pattern was obviously too heavy to handle, instead i used this one "[\\W+]" which increased the performance a lot. I don't have the same results, but it works great.

Comment: @user974594 - If you end up needing to give up on regular expressions and have to roll your own, consider a state-machine implementation.  Use a BitSet to represent the alphabetics that you need - for that kind of set it's the fastest, and it's easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't already doing it, use BufferedInputStream and BufferedReader to read the files. Double-buffering like that is measurably better than using BufferedInputStream or BufferedReader alone. E.g.:

```
BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
        new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(aFile)
        )
        /* add an encoding arg here (e.g., ', "UTF-8"') if appropriate */
    )
);
```

If you post relevant parts of your code, there'd be a chance we could comment on how to improve the processing.

EDIT:

Based on your edit, here are a couple of suggestions:

1. Compile the pattern once and save it as a static variable, rather than compiling every time you call `parseString`.
2. Store the values of `temp.indexOf(key)` and `temp.indexOf(value)` when you first call them and then use the stored values instead of calling `indexOf` a second time.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Sounds perfectly logic, waste of resources compiling the pattern so many times and calling tones of times indexOf. It is running now, gonna see if performance improves

Comment: added another screen. Please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Try to use to single regex that has a group that matches each word that is within tags - so a single regex could be used for your entire input and there would be not separate "split" stage.

Otherwise your approach seems reasonable, although I don't understand what you mean by "get the String [] ..." - I thought you were using an ArrayList. In any event, try to minimize the creation of objects, for both construction cost and garbage collection cost.

Comment: i first split the sentence and save it in String []. Then, for each String[i], i save in a map, adding or increasing word frequency

Answer (score 1):

Is it just the parsing that's taking so long, or is it the file reading as well?

For the file reading, you can probably speed that up by reading the files on multiple threads. But first step is to figure out whether it's the reading or the parsing that's taking all the time so you can address the right issue.

Comment: exactly, i dont know what's taking so long. I would need to find it, and then address it here

Answer (score 1):

Run the code through the Netbeans profiler and find out where it is taking the most time (right mouse click on the project and select profile, make sure you do time not memory).

Comment: i'v never did something similar. Now it is running, gona wait the results and post here. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code that you have shown us is an obvious source of performance problems.  The problem is likely to be something to do with the way that you are parsing the lines or extracting the words and putting them into the map.  If you want more advice you need to post the code for those methods, and the code that declares / initializes the map.

My general advice would be to profile the application and see where the bottlenecks are, and use that information to figure out what needs to be optimized.

@Ed Staub's advice is also sound.  Running an application with a heap that is too small *can* result serious performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like its spending most of it time in regular expressions.  I would firstly try writing the code without using a regular expression and then using multiple threads as if the process still appears to be CPU bound.

For the counter, I would look at using TObjectIntHashMap to reduce the overhead of the counter. I would use only one map, not create an array of string - counts which I then use to build another map, this could be a significant waste of time.

Comment: yes. It is actually the pattern that is consuming most of the time. But it is perfectly working, besides the high time performance, the pattern is what i need. Any other idea? @EJP

Comment: You need to re-test it to find where the bottleneck is now. I still would reconsider removing the regex, if this provide to be the bottle neck.

Answer (score 0):

Precompile the pattern instead of compiling it every time through that method, and rid of the double buffering: use new BufferedReader(new FileReader(...)).